# Kafka Connect: When sinking happens?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Suppose I have a topic named `orders` which has two consumer groups and I want to sink it to a MySQL database. Does sink connector waits for those two consumers to finish their job then sink the data or it doesn't care and starts the sink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sink connectors create their own consumer group.

Consumer groups are independent of one another; there is no waiting.